# JPA Buddy Reverse Engineering is not showing tables

Tags: mysql, jpa, intellij-idea, jdbc

When I right click and select "Entities from DB" it correctly connects to my MySQL Database, and it succesfully performs the introspection, so that I can see the list of tables from the IntelliJ side view. But within the popup I get 0 tables, 0 views but all relations

It looks like this:

[IntelliJ Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qomRQ.png)

Do you have any suggestions?

I already tried the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248414/the-jpa-buddy-reverse-engineering-tool-is-not-showing-tables/75255880#75255880)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it went away after recreating the database connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).